# Does a helicopter battery drain when it is "off" but attached to a battery hot bus?

Tags: power-supply, batteries, dc, ground, bus

I'm reading about the `DC Power System` for a civilian helicopter.
It shows the following diagram for when the battery is off:
[image]

However, it shows that the `battery hot bus` will still be energized.

I assume the `battery hot bus` is grounded completing the circuit.
Doesn't this mean the battery would be draining with the helicopter off?

What is the purpose of a battery hot bus, and how does it affect the battery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the same setup as a typical automotive/car/truck electrical system.

You have a ***Switched*** bus, that's only on when the key is on Acc/On. The Key Ignition switch enables a power relay to power most of the car, like radio, windows, AC, and further for the Starter Motor. High drain devices that only need to be on if the user is already in the car.

Then you have an ***Always On*** bus. These are directly connected to the battery, without any relay. Typically, this will be alarm systems, keyless entry, door locks, some headlights, some cigarette/power outlets, clocks, the ODB-2 or CAN-Bus system, some lights. Most of these are very low current draw systems, or not constantly active without user interaction (roof light, headlights, motorized windows, electronic locks).

#### Yes, the battery is slowly draining with the Always On bus, it's just designed to be very low draw, with active use/recharging.

This is why you are typically expected to use the car on the regular, to prevent this from even being notice. Letting a car sit for a week isn't normally an issue, but ***Long term sitting/non-use***, like weeks (or a month for new/good batteries), will drain it enough to need a jump. Long term storage recommendations are to disconnect the battery completely, or use a battery tender.

This is also why leaving the headlights or map lights on will drain the car overnight. These are Always On/Hot systems. Same for any Always On cigarette outlets with a cell phone charger or similar.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the particular model, but typically a hot bus is used for things like maintaining clocks, and keeping medium-term memory for things like GPS almanacs (but not database updates, which would be stored more permanently).

In most applications, the drain is low enough that the battery should be left connected all the time, but I know at least one instance of a business jet that the users typically disconnect because of high drain on the hot bus.

It's possible the only way to know would be to ask someone who uses it regularly, or use a multimeter to measure the load when the master is off.

Answer (score 1):

I am no helicopter expert, but I know something about battery systems.

When you have a battery powered system, even when it is fully off, there usually is something on.

Think of your smartphone: when you turn it on you just briefly press a button. This button is connected to an integrated circuit, which is then energized, so that when it senses that the button is pressed it can power the CPU and wake up the system.

For a nice smartphone I would expect the battery to last forever. The standby power consumed by this IC is probably way less than the auto discharge current of the battery.

Now to your helicopter.
Looking at the schematic it seems that when BR is disengaged the battery is not powering anything. The battery hot bus does not seem to be connected to anything and no, it is not grounded. Circuits are completed to ground *through a load*.

But I suspect that's not the full story. On a system complicated as an helicopter I would be very surprised if there is no system permanently connected to the battery hot bus, there probably are some low power blocks that are kept on in order to speed up the boot process of the machine.

This blocks are probably listed somewhere in the manual. I bet that disconnecting the battery for long term storage requires a precise procedure and checklist, you might want to check that section out and see if there is any warning about a long power on time because of some systems that need time to boot, and are usually kept always on via bat hot bus. A thing that comes to mind is GPS, possibly helicopters use something like AGPS to get a quicker fix. If this is not stored in permanent memory, after a battery disconnect the data needs to be downloaded from scratch.

Comment: Each one of those rectangles should have its own set of sheets that shows what breakers and loads are connected to it. This is just a high-level diagram of the bus structure.